# "filed value" is coming like ‘1123456@lopoa’ format

Tags: java

If in java `filed value` is coming like `1123456@lopoa` format. 
So My question I am trying to take the value before `@`.

So according to java what to do to implement this logic?

Comment: string.split(@)[0]

Comment: string.substring(0, string.indexOf("@"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method of `String` class.

Following is working code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String val = "1123456@lopoa";
    String[] vals = val.split("@");
    System.out.println(vals[0]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1123456
```

See it working [here](https://ideone.com/roPPJR)